# Problem escaping text which contains html markups

Tags: theme-development

I am working on a theme and when i use NS Theme Check Plugin to check my theme for errors and warnings I receive a lots of this warnings

> WARNING   Expected next thing to be an escaping function (see Codex for 'Data Validation')

I exactly know that I need to escape the data before i can use in within any html. But here lies my problem .
In many scenario the string consist of html and variables(variables which is already escaped). Example would be

```
  echo get_category_parents($ID, TRUE, ' </li>', FALSE);
```

The get_category_parents() return

```
<a href="link_to_category">Catgeory</a>
```

Now when I try to escape the entire line as

```
echo esc_html(get_category_parents($ID, TRUE, ' </li>', FALSE),'default');
```

The entire html markup is treated as a string. which is not recognized as a valid html markup by a browser.

And above is just one scenario. There are lots of such scenario. What could be a possible way to handle such situation.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape html content you can use `wp_kses` function.

```
$allowed = array(
    'li' => array(),
    'a' => array(
        'href' => true,
    ),
);

echo wp_kses('<li><a href="#" target="_blank">Category</a></li>', $allowed);
```

If you do not want to pass allowed array you can use default WordPress array for post content which is used in `wp_kses_post` function.

```
echo wp_kses_post('<li><a href="#" target="_blank">Category</a></li>');
```

Comment: Thank you. Are there any possible way to escape without passing bunch of html's array

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: will try that too...thank you. Lets see if it doesn't throw up any escape warnings